# Update Does Not Work in VS2010 Using IDB2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ibm-midrange

I have no problem when trying to execute and insert or a delete SQL Command. However, this update command does not seems to work well and I am having a hard time to figure it out. Kindly help me please.

I am using an i Series or AS/400 database.

```
Imports IBM.Data.DB2
Imports IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries
Public conn As New iDB2Connection
Public str As String = "Datasource=10.0.1.11;UserID=edith;password=edith;DefaultCollection=impexplib"
Dim cmdUpdate As New iDB2Command
Dim sqlUpdate As String
conn = New iDB2Connection(str)
conn.Open()
sqlUpdate = "UPDATE impexplib.expusers SET loginDate=@loginDate, loginTime=@loginTime WHERE username=@username"
cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("username", iDB2DbType.iDB2VarChar)
cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("loginDate", iDB2DbType.iDB2Date)
cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("loginTime", iDB2DbType.iDB2Time)
cmdUpdate.Parameters("username").Value = txtUsername.Text
cmdUpdate.Parameters("loginDate").Value = Now.ToString("d")
cmdUpdate.Parameters("loginTime").Value = Now.ToString("T")
cmdUpdate.Connection = conn
cmdUpdate.CommandText = sqlUpdate
cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
```

Please help me what I am doing wrong? The update code does not really work. Even a simple update of password does not work to.

Thanks!

Comment: Please expand "does not seem to work well": please define explicitly in what way it does not do what you expect.

Comment: the update does not really do anything at all. it does not update the database. it does not change the value of the loginDate & loginTime.

Comment: Please update your question to that effect, and then you'll need to wait on someone who knows AS/400 over ADO.NET (to me, as generic SQL, it looks OK).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no error messages anywhere, if no update is occurring, then the WHERE clause is not being satisfied.  Make sure that the user name in DB2 exactly matches the parameter used in the WHERE clause.  Very often, DB2 columns are CHAR, not VARCHAR or the other way round.  You may also have a situation where the DB2 column is all upper case and the parameter is mixed case.  Imagine the DB2 column has "FRED BLOGGS          " and your parameter has "Fred Bloggs".  This won't satisfy the WHERE clause and no rows will be updated.

Comment: i tried to capitalize the field names, even the table names but it really doesn't work. The update query is really not working at all. Nothing happens to the database :(

Comment: It's not a question of capitalising the field names, it's a question of the contents of the variable and the column you're trying to match against.